# Remove items from a char * C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, char, character

I am trying to remove characters from a char pointer and would like to store them back in a new char pointer variable let's say "temp". So I would have something like this:

```
char *test = "1@2#3$4%5^6&7*8!9@1#0";
char *temp = "";
```

then remove the "@,#,$,%,^,*,!,@,#," and place the new values of "12345678910" into *temp. This would make temp be equal to "12345678910".

Is this possible?

I have been doing this with string but I really need to do this with the char pointers. Here is how I have done this with string:

```
std::string str("1@2#3$4%5^6&7*8!9@1#0");
std::string temp("");

    char chars[] = "@#$%^&*!";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); ++i)
   {
       str.erase (std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), chars[i]), str.end());

    }
    temp = str;
```

So you see here I am doing this all will strings but I just cannot seem to get away with asigning a char * variable like test to a string because its an illegal conversion. However why am I able to set my char * variables equal to string like so?

```
char *test = "123456789";
```

However this is illegal?

```
std::string str("1@2#3$4%5^6&7*8!9@1#0");

    char chars[] = "@";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); ++i)
   {
       str.erase (std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), chars[i]), str.end());

    }

    char *test = str; //Illegal point
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you need to use `char *`? `std::string` was designed largely because using `char *` for strings is pointlessly painful. You might also want to clarify what characters you want to keep/remove -- do you just want to remove `@`, or just keep decimal digits, or what exactly?

Comment: This looks like a job for regular expressions

Comment: If you need to use char * for strings (I'm guessing because you're using old-style interfaces to functions), then use string.c_str(). Don't both trying to manipulate char * directly - they're not arrays and shouldn't be treated like arrays

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Yes I am sorry I needed to remove all items except the numbers so it returned "12345678910".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
char *test = str;
```

into:

```
char *test = str.c_str();
```

**c_str** is a method that creates c style char array from original string for you.

EDIT: this is a more safe way, a copy of the c string will be obtained:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
...
char *test = strdup(str.c_str());
... // process the string
free(test);
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) you have a reference to std string class.
Manpage for [strdup](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strdup).

Comment: You have to be careful with `c.str()` as it returns the internal `char*`, which will be erased when the `str` destructor is called, and anyway can be moved from time to time. Better make a copy of it if you want to keep it.

Comment: Ok great! Thank you for this. i just have to test real quick and then I will get back to you. Thanks so much for the quick response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok i tried to make a copy of it like so :
`const char *temp = str.c_str(); const char *final = *temp;` But it says "a value of type "char" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const char *" Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Sorry, comment was incorreclty input.

Comment: `final=temp` will not copy the string. You need to use `strcpy`. Or use my other solution that doesn't use `std::string` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do with iterators you can also do with pointers to an array. Say, an array of chars:

```
char str[] = "1@2#3$4%5^6&7*8!9@1#0";

char chars[] = "@";

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); ++i)
{
   *std::remove(str, str+strlen(str), chars[i])=0;

}
```

Notice that I used the fact that `std::remove` returns an `iterator` (in this case `char*`) to the "one after last" element and set that char to 0 - making sure it stays a zero-delimited string